# Trinomial lattice model movement probability calculation under various models

Tags: interest-rates

I need to construct trinomial lattice model movement probability calculation under various models Vasicek, Hull White, Ho Lee and Hull White Two Factor.

I do not see any reference to these models with trinomial lattice framework.

Please can anyone point to references or other resources. I am specifically looking for up movement and down movement probabilities and methods to find them for any base model.